# php check if last char of a sub string is whitespace

Tags: php, string, whitespace

I am trying to check if the last char of a substring is a white space. The input string is to be cut into substring of length < 138 with one condition, if the char at position 138 is not a white space, then the length is reduced until the last (previous) whitespace. The string is sent from a textarea by post.

Here is what I have:

```
$numOfsubstring = ceil(mb_strlen($_POST['myInput'], 'UTF-8') / 138);
$begin = 0;
$len = 138;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $numOfsubstring; $i++){

// the following while loops doesn't seems to be working ...
while(ctype_space(mb_substr($_POST['myInput'], $len, 1)) != true){
    $len = $len - 1; 
}

$subString = mb_substr($_POST['myInput'], $begin, $len) . " - $i";
echo $subString;
$begin = $begin + 138;
}
```

I was able to achieve this using JS but failed to do so with php!!

Comment: try to use strrpos(' ',your substring variable) == 0 or 1. just check your self

Comment: This seems to be a good idea, I will give it a try.. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

you could right-trim the string.. if the string no longer matches the original string, then it must have had white space

```
if (rtrim($my_substring) != $my_substring) {
 // ...
}
```

Comment: I will give this some thoughts, I am not sure about **have had** part as it suggests that the check would be afterword while I'd prefer to check before.